# apt install snapd gives Err:1 404 Not Found

Tags: apt

`apt-update` and `apt-upgrade` does not help this problem.

[404 not found screencap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RU3WV.png)

As you can see, this file genuinely does not exist at the given archive website.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aTPVR.png)

What are my options now?

Comment: [Ubuntu 18.04 LTS has reached the end of it's *standard* support life](https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2023/05/13/extended-security-maintenance-for-ubuntu-18-04-bionic-beaver-begins-31-may-2023/) thus is now off-topic here unless your question is specific to helping you move to a *fully supported* release of Ubuntu.  Ubuntu 18.04 ESM support is available, but not on-topic here, see https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic  See also https://ubuntu.com//blog/18-04-end-of-standard-support

Comment: FYI:  I'd return to the `sudo apt update` you mention as not helping... ie. read the output it gives you & ensure there were no warnings, errors, missing lines, extra/contradictory lines etc.. however you're off-topic here now, with 20.04 the oldest *standard support* release of Ubuntu that is on-topic on this site.